# How to find out what IP address a Windows (Vista) application connects to

Tags: connection, ip, ip-address

Basically I need to find out where an application X connects to (ip or domain name) and what data is being passed back and force. The application is plain Windows app, system is Windows Vista.
The connection is very quick and something like netstat does now show it - is there a way to show past connections using netstats or other program?
I suspect a connection is HTTP, so if this is true, knowing the full URL would be nice to have too.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: It sounds like Wireshark might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/); it allows you to monitor all incoming and outgoing network traffic on your machine and has a ton of advanced filtering options.

Answer (score 1):

You could also find your programs PID, and run `netstat -o` in cmd, this command lists all active connections and the PID thats using it.